# ajax navigation different folders

Tags: jquery, ajax

First let me show the folder structure

main(folder)

pages(folder) and inside pages folder i have 5 html pages.
and in the main folder i have the js,index.php, and load.php

heres the code for index.php

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" class="active" id="page1-link">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2" id="page2-link">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3" id="page3-link">Page 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page4" id="page4-link">Page 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>

<div id="main-content">
    <?php include('pages/page1.html'); ?>
</div>
```

I made an ajax navigation and the problem i have right now is i dont know how to make a link inside pages(folder) go to another certain page without refreshing too.

The code is working fine but what if i have a link inside the pages(folder) which is for example: page1, and i want it to go to another certain page without refreshing.

I have tried making a custom js again inside the pages(folder) but it's not working.
Is there any other way around it?

Comment: hmm you can send param trough url ,
For example yoururl.com#pageView=page1
Then read pageView param on # change , and make function that will change your main content.

Adding dynamic #something to your url wont refresh your page.
This is all possible with jquery. If you want to see full code , i can post answer.

Comment: If your link to pages/page1.html works then a link to pages/page2.html should work as well because you are replacing the content on index.html so technically you are on index.html the entire time.  Am I understanding your problem correctly?.

Comment: hmm no, the link is in the  pages/page1.html that is replacing the content on index.html but  pages/page1.html wont be able to read the custom.js cuz its in different folder so it will not have any extension like for example .html or .php

Comment: @noitse yes please i want to see the full code

Answer (score 0):

Ill write my solution i used to use ,using jQuery. The idea is you will send custom parametar of page you want to load through URL.I hope this is what you are aiming for

Example test.com#pageView=myPage

The idea is next , you have your mainPage.html and its js file.
Inside mainPage.html there is div with class main-content.

Inside mainPage js file , you are checking for hash change for pageViews.
Reading url which should be something.com#pageView=yourPage, you get what page you want to open , in this case yourPage.

We are loading page with jquery through div selector and .load function, i have put fixed that it goes inside folder pages,  you can send whole location of page through url as well , example something.com#pageView=location/pageView

To access url we will make function getUrlVars

```
function getUrlVars() { 
    var vars = [], hash;
    var indexofHash = window.location.href.indexOf('#');
    var hashes;
    if (indexofHash == -1) {
        hashes = window.location.href.slice((window.location.href.indexOf('?')) + 1).split('&');
    } else {
        hashes = window.location.href.slice((window.location.href.indexOf('#')) + 1).split('&');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

So our js should have on document ready , to check which page we want to load , and on #change.

```
 var $pageView = $('.main-content')

 $(document).on('ready', function () { 
        var loadPage = getUrlVars()["pageView"]
        if(loadPage == undefined || loadPage == ''){ //Load home page
            $pageView.load("pages/home.html", function () {  
                //After load 
            });
        }else{ 
            $pageView.load("pages/"+loadPage+".html",function(){ 
                //After page load
            })
        } 
    });
```

And on #change is preaty much same

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) { 
    var loadPage = getUrlVars()["pageView"] 
    if (loadPage == undefined && loadPage == '') {  
        $pageView.load("pages/home.html", function () {
           //After page load
        });
    } else {
        $pageView.load("pages/" + loadPage + ".html", function () {
            //After page load
        }); 
    }
});
```

You can add loader in begining of functions , and remove them after page load.

Now a href should look like something like href="#pageView=page1"

Comment: so if i do that code make make an <a href="#page4" id="page4-link"></a> inside page1.html that is inside the folder of pages will it load the #page4 content?

Comment: @AliceManalangLacanilao you can do that as well , then you dont need get url vars , you can use window.location.hash , which will return ur hash value, but i used pageView , so i can send multiple params after my page.
For example ufl.com#pageView=userProfile&userCode=something

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. hmm can you plase look at this website cuz i got the code from here [link](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/02/how-to-supercharge-your-sites-speed-with-ajax-and-jquery/)
Please download the demo 2 and try adding a link at page 2 that will go to the page 1 `<a href="#page1">` and telll me if it works thanks

Comment: @AliceManalangLacanilao Looking at both demo's online , they seem to work,i dont know what problem you are facing, if you are using my code , and my way of href, and having a problem , please try to debug , alert your loadPage , and pageView to see if there is a problem.

Comment: did you add the link at page1? cuz the pages are in different folder so it wont be able to read the js that's why i asked you to add it :)

Comment: huh....I gave you functional code , that you need to change a bit so it will work with yours. I cant just go and change href at some random page,  not knowing what you did with js, 

Ill edit main post one more time for you to understand what is the point.

If you want me to help you more. Please setup jsfiddle pointing your problem.